# how to show css text in html div

Tags: css

I am trying to show the information in the `notice` class.

I have try adding `content:` but this doesn't work.

```
.notice {
color:red;
content: "information below are instructions for this method for this page";
}

<div class="notice"></div>
```

I was wondering if the text in the `content` can be shown in the `div`?. I want to show actually what is in the `notice` class whenever I call the `notice` class. I have about 40 pages I need to do this to and some people might thing I should just type it in all pages but that `information` in the `content` changes.

Is they a way to do this in css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `content` property only works on the `:after` and `:before` psuedo classes, e.g. try:

```
.notice {
color:red;
}
.notice:after{
content: "information below are instructions for this method for this page";
}

<div class="notice"></div>
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GMt5N/3/)

That said, CSS should be kept for styling and not content - which should be output in your HTML, and controlled by either whichever serverside tech you're using (e.g. PHP, Python), or a JS bridge.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean exactly but textual content should typically be separated from CSS, which should remain for styling only. You can use CSS to show/hide text held/written in your HTML, but this content will be outside of any CSS you specify. The :before and :after selectors being the exception

Comment: looking at your example in fiddle it works. Yes I know it will easy but I am using Apex oracle so I will follow your advert and use Jquery for this

Answer (score 0):

I think i your case it is better to make a `PHP if` statement for the `notice`. that would be pretty more usefull